# Facing trouble with Gulp package installation

Tags: npm, gulp

```
{
  "name": "school",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-util": "latest",
    "gulp-rename": "latest",
    "map-stream": "latest",
    "gulp-livereload": "latest",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "latest",
    "gulp-watch": "latest"
  }
}
```

And when I run gulp command on my cmd there is an error saying cannot find module 'gulp-rename' and so on...Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: Then what does your gulp script (`gulpfile.js`) actually look like?

Comment: issue resolved. I was running the npm install at the wrong place. Thank you so much phil.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use `npm install` before run `gulp`

run `npm install` will install all devDependencies.